# Why does the amount of time required to train Jedi decrease?

Tags: star-wars

Many Younglings are as young as 4, which gives them decades to master the Force.  In *The Empire Strikes Back*, Yoda tells Obi-Wan's Force ghost that Luke is "too old" to begin training. Luke is only 22. While in *The Phantom Menace*, Mace Windu says the 9-year-old Anakin is too old to begin training. Rey is 19 in *The Force Awakens* and *The Last Jedi* and by the age of 20, she's able to use the Force like a Jedi master. In the training scene flashback in *The Rise of Skywalker*, Leia is over the age of 22. So, only a few decades after the eradication of the Jedi who served the Galactic Republic, these new Jedi students can be older, and attain mastery in "much less time" than the Jedi of centuries past could.

Comment: _"He is too old. There is already too much anger in him."_ The young age was due to attachments and feelings rather than much else. In the later films they mostly ignore that because they don't really have much other choice.

Comment: Luke is one of the most powerful Jedi of all time and Rey is a direct descendant of the Emperor.  The usual rules don't apply to prodigies.

Comment: After Order 66 all the midichlorians got concentrated into super powerful force users who don't need training. I kid, but it probably has something to do with the entire infrastructure and bureaucracy of the Jedi education system being gone as well as much of the history curriculum and all but a few ancient texts. Just needing to preserve what is still remembered and working with what they've got. (older individuals).

Comment: @L.T.Smash If Yoda gave a damn about restoring peace & order to the Republic, then he must have known that he "could not" follow the rigid tradition of only accepting students between the ages of 4 and 8. Then by the time Luke had attained a decent level of mastery, he knew "full-well" that an age limit of 8 was just preposterous, if he wanted to build a New Jedi Order.

Comment: It's the converse of Parkinson's law.

Comment: Ever considered that the Jedi order is more about control of people than training them?

Comment: I've always thought that the "old" training regime had a lot of "unnecessary" ancient baggage, stuff you "had" to do or learn "just because" your teachers had to too. Yoda and later Luke realized, out of necessity, that all that stuff just wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 7):

There are two primary answers to this:

### They are intently powerful in the Force

The Skywalker and Palpatine bloodlines are strong in the Force and so they not only have great power, but a strong attachment to the Force.

### Luke and Rey were not fully trained

Both Luke and Rey were taught enough to survive. They had strength, and learned quickly, but what they learned was not the full breadth of Jedi mastery. They do have access to a lot of the teaching texts courtesy of Luke's efforts to find everything he could.

### Ultimately, it might be for the best

While the Jedi were a great source of good in the universe, they also became a rigid bureaucratic organization that tore children away from their family and raised them to avoid all emotional attachment, which is not healthy. The events of *The Book of Boba Fett* suggest that Luke is continuing in this path of eschewing emotional attachment, and by the time of the sequel films, he is the last Jedi again. Maybe, this is a case where losing those centuries of tradition is a good thing, that the long course of Jedi training was as much about indoctrination as training then in the ways of the Force.